# Why is it considered method hiding if a parent and child class have a static method with the same name?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, static

If you declare an inheritance hierarchy where both the parent and child class have a static method of the same name and parameters*, Visual Studio will raise warning [CS0108](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3s8070fc.aspx):

Example:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
    }
}
```

`: warning CS0108: 'SubClass.DoSomething()' hides inherited member 'BaseClass.DoSomething()'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended.`

Why is this considered method hiding?  Neither method is involved in the inheritance hierarchy and can only be invoked by using the class name:

```
BaseClass.DoSomething();
SubClass.DoSomething();
```

or, unqualified in the class itself.  In either case, there is no ambiguity as to which method is being called (i.e., no 'hiding').

*Interestingly enough, the methods can differ by return type and still generate the same warning.  However, if the method parameter types differ, the warning is not generated.

Please note that I am not trying to create an argument for or discuss static inheritance or any other such nonsense.

Comment: One thing for sure - methods are not differenciated by return type in c#. This is not the case with staticness, this is with every type of method. Nor they are differenciated with their access modifier

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Members of the SubClass will not be able to access the DoSomething from BaseClass without explicitly indicating the class name. So it is effectively "hidden" to members of SubClass, but still accessible.

For example:

```
public class SubClass : BaseClass
{
    public static void DoSomething()
    {
    }

    public static void DoSomethingElse()
    {
        DoSomething(); // Calls SubClass
        BaseClass.DoSomething(); // Calls BaseClass
    }
}
```

Comment: Good example, though not as convincing as the rationale for non-static, virtual methods.  Maybe a better example would be if `DoSomethingElse()` were declared in a SubSubClass.

Comment: @Travis - Good Point. The further down the inheritance chain you go, the more confusing it could be :-)

Answer (score 3):

> Why is this considered method hiding? Neither method is involved in the inheritance hierarchy and can only be invoked by using the class name.

That is not true. You can call DoSomething from any inherited class name:

```
public Class A
{
     public static void C() {...}
}

public Class B: A
{

}

B.C() // Valid call!
```

That is why you are hiding C() if you declare the method with the same signature in B.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I had considered this, but it seems idiotic.  Calling B.C() does work, but the intent is questionable.  If you introduce method C within B afterwards, recompiling would change it to call the newly introduced method.  Note, if you don't recompile the B.C() call (if it is in a different assembly, etc), it will still refer to A.C().

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. That is precisely why the compiler warns you when you implement B.C(): you might by mistake make any caller expecting A.C() when calling through B call B.C() unknowingly. If you add the 'new' keyword you are explicitly letting the compiler know that you want to hide A's implementation of C() and make any caller from B resolve to B.C() (note that A.C() will still execute the original implementation in A).

Comment: Maybe a better question is "Why does B.C() even compile?" to begin with. =)  Your argument makes sense for instance methods since they are inherited.  Static methods are not, though through allowing something like B.C() to compile (when B does not declare a C method) creates that illusion.  I think @CodeNaked's answer reflects a more practical example.

Comment: Why B.C() compiles is an excellent point, but thats not the issue at hand. The fact is that it does compile and therefore the warning makes sense. Otherwise you would be hiding a method defined in A with no feedback at all. Warning is obviously the better option.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a warning. The compiler just wants to make sure you intentionally used the same method name.

Comment: And if I didn't intentionally use the same method name, what is the problem?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. By specifying "new" explicitly, you're telling the compiler you meant to use the same method signature.

Comment: I think InBetween explains it best in their answer including where your base assumptions seem to be wrong.

Comment: Consider non-static methods.  If I have two methods with the same name, and I am making a call, there is potential ambiguity.  In the static case, that ambiguity does not exist as easily (though see @CodeNaked's response for a similar example of where it could exist)

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio, and Philippe, are saying it's a warning so your code will compile and run.

However, 'CodeNaked' nicely demonstrates why it is hidden. This code compiles without throwing errors or warnings. Thanks to 'CodeNaked'

```
public class BaseClass {
    public virtual void DoSomething() {
    }
}

public class SubClass : BaseClass {
    public override void DoSomething() {

    }

    public void DoSomethingElse() {
        DoSomething(); // Calls SubClass
        base.DoSomething(); // Calls BaseClass
    }
}
```

EDIT:
With Travis's code I can do the following:
            BaseClass.DoSomething();
            SubClass.DoSomething();

And it works fine. Thing is though you might wonder why SubClass is inheriting from BaseClass and both are implementing the same static methods. Actually that's not true, both classes are implementing methods that could be completely different but have the same name. That could be potential confusing.

Comment: I think the confusion is related to the static classes so removing that keyword everywhere doesn't really help answer the question. If you made your methods all static I think you'd be getting some warnings or possibly even errors.

Comment: This is a great example - of why I asked the question about static methods.  The instance method case with virtual/non-virtual methods makes complete sense.  Static is where it gets a little hair-raising.

Comment: With the above code if you add the static keyword you'll get errors and the code won't compile. The thing is with static classes and methods is that the class doesn't have to be instantiated first.